# How to use ForceReply in telegram bot api using python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot

I wanted my bot to send an image to the user, and user has to reply for that specific image only. And Store his reply as a string in a variable. So used `sendPhoto` method along with a dictionary called files which include attributes `photo` which has the URL of image and a `reply_markup` which i set to ForceReply. Everythings fine but i coudnt see the force reply. And i coudnt get what the user has replied after i(bot) sent an image.

```
files = {'photo': open("/home/preetham/Downloads/selenium/cap.jpg", 'rb'),
         'reply_markup':'ForceReply'}
status = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/[MY BOT API HERE]/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + UserID, files=files)
```

The above code is able to send image but is not able to force reply.
When a user type a reply after he received this photo and if i try to grab the message he replied i always get the previous message but not the recent one and i used the below code.

```
while True:
    try:
        js = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/[MY BOT API HERE/getUpdates").json()
        reply = js['result'][-1]['message']['text']
        if len(reply) > 0:
            print('Reply received')
            break
        else:
            continue
    except:
        continue
```

How can i apply Force reply to the photo i sent ? How can i get the reply given for that photo ?